# Return the binary encoded in Base64 wrapped in Xml

Tags: xml, asp-classic, vbscript

The current web service that resides in a file 'image.asp'.

It pulls out the parameter 'path' and loads that filepath from the file repo.
This returns the binary directly to e.g. the web browser that invoked the
service and then renders the e.g. PDF in the browser.

---

```
<%
If Request.QueryString.Count > 0 then
    Dim fileStream
    Dim fileLoc

    fileLoc= Request.QueryString("path")

    Set fileStream = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")

    fileStream.Type=1
    fileStream.Mode=3

    fileStream.open
    fileStream.loadFromFile fileLoc

    Response.Buffer = False 
    Response.ContentType = "image/tiff"

    Response.BinaryWrite fileStream.read

    fileStream.close
    Response.Flush()

    Set fileStream = Nothing

else
'querystring parameters present

end if
%>

-----------------------------------------------------------
```

What I would like to do is to return the binary encoded in Base64
and wrapped up in an xml message e.g.

```
<response>
    <file-content>878748759459843u989856589u96u9yu9.......</file-content>
</response>
```

This blob post here..

http://ghads.wordpress.com/2008/10/17/vbscript-readwrite-binary-encodedecode-base64/

..appears to contain VBScript code adequate for base64 encoding binary.

Comment: So, what'you your SPECIFIC question?

Comment: Am I going about this with the right approach? So I convert the binary to base64 and inject it into an xml file to be saved. How else would people go about this. thanks

Comment: Seems safe. JSON is also an option.